# How to change the text Size of Spinner run time

Tags: android, text, size, runtime, spinner

I have a android spinner. I want to change the size of the spinner text (selected text from the dropdown) run time. I have a button on whose onCLick event I want to do the size change of few things. All other texts are changing by setTextSize() but there are issues with spinner. I have taken the reference of the textview used in getView() of my custom  spinner adapter. I apply setTextSize() on it. The first Time it changes the size of he spinner but by again pressing the button ever thing (other textViews on the screen) change their size but not the spinner. Please help..

Regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try this code 
    Spinner sp_state = new Spinner(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    sp_state.setLayoutParams(lp);

    ArrayAdapter<String> state_Adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getParent(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ARRLIST_STATE){
          public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(12);
                ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                return v;
        }


    };
```

state_Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp_state.setAdapter(driver_state_Adapter);

Answer (score 1):

If you are using customize Adapter.Then you have to use one Base Adapter class like in List View.The xml file you inflate, can be used as you want.You can increase size there

**Edited**
[Refer to this link for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281069/how-to-change-spinner-text-size)

Comment: hi Thanks for the response. I am new to android. I have my custom Adapter where I overwrite the getView() and getDropDownView(). I have the refrerence of the textView which i obtain from the convertView, passed as a parameter to the getView(). I apply setTextSize(myDynamicSize) to that textView. Once the size is changing but then second time nothing happens to the spinner size. Hope I have made the context a bit clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have problem then you attach a simple Listview like adapter to Spinner.And can play with this